# Loading properties from external sources in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Here is my use case:

I have only the `db.userName` available in properties file. I don't have `db.password` available in my local property file.

In my java class i have

Class A {

```
@Value("${db.userName}")
String userName;

@Value("${db.password}")
String  userPassword;
```

}

I would like to resolve db.password by making a REST call to an external service which stores the passwords in a centralized place.

How do I do this in Spring 3.1 ? I tried extending  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Create `app.properties` file under `resources` folder and put there your data:

```
db.userName=karthik
db.password=
```

Then use it like:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/app.properties")
public class A {

    @Value("#{db.userName}")
    String userName;

    @Value("#{db.password}")
    String userPassword;
}
```

Read some more info on [Spring Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html).

---

You can also create your database configuration class and configure `DataSource` bean like:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("app.properties")
public class DataConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
        ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My requirement is slightly different. I want to call a REST API to get the value of the property. The rest API will return the decrypted password.

Comment: Also i am adding this REST API call as an enhancement and i cannot afford lot of changes to the way the current code is implemented

Answer (score 0):

- Consume rest service in getter, although I recommend you to implement service for that.

  ```
  private String getUserPassword(){
      final String uri = "url/get-db-paswword";

      RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
      return restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
  }
  ```